# Parity SMS Verification failed

Tags: parity, kovan

I have tried to verify my account by SMS method so I can request Kovan ethers.

I have followed this video https://youtu.be/99UucFzYCRc.
Unfortunately someting have messed up (I have changed transaction fee and was also switching between tabs, can't really tell exact steps) and after signing transaction I was not redirected to tab with text *"The transaction has been posted to the network with a hash of..."*
The same situation occured once again.

These are performed transactions:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb5e37be779bb78ada4eab56897e0844baa267d7161c7432d0dcd27d956fd1496
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x19feedcb37b260695905a7ccae7d13e9a0f82d45d321260ade28088e37a7bd21

I have not received any SMS, account is still unverified, lost ~ $8.

Is this possible to resume verification process from this transactions?